# SQL Select part of string

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a string that looks a bit like the following:

> 189 A 190 Merit 191 68.6

Now I want the value that falls between `190` and `191` - `Merit`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you always search for `190` and `191` or is there any other rule?

Comment: You need to provide more than one example, preferable exposing any "interesting" cases (different positions? no value?), if you want a decent answer. At the moment, `SELECT 'merit'` would be a valid query satisfying your requirements.

Comment: I will always be searching for a value that is between 190 and 191 (it never changes). Such as 189 B 190 Pass 191 50.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being naive - you say you have a string (i.e. not a column).

```
declare @astring nvarchar(max);
set @astring = '189 A 190 Merit 191 68.6';
```

The next 2 statements strip out the part between 190 and 191.

```
set @astring = stuff(@astring,1,patindex('%190%',@astring)+2,'');
set @astring = stuff(@astring,patindex('%191%',@astring+'191'),len(@astring),'');
set @astring = LTRIM(RTRIM(@astring));

select @astring;  -- 'Merit'
```

---

If you had meant a table column, then

```
declare @t table (astring nvarchar(max));
insert @t select
'189 A 190 Merit 191 68.6' union all select
'189 A 19 Merit 191 68.6 oops bad string' union all select
'' union all select -- make sure it doesn't crash on empty string
null union all select -- ditto null
'189 C 190 Pass 191 50.1';

select astring, s2=stuff(s1,patindex('%191%',s1+'191'),len(s1),'')
from
(
select astring, s1=stuff(astring,1,patindex('%190%',astring+'190')+2,'')
from @t
) x

-- result
ASTRING                                      S2
189 A 190 Merit 191 68.6                     Merit
189 A 19 Merit 191 68.6 oops bad string      (null)
                                             (null)
(null)                                       (null)
189 C 190 Pass 191 50.1                      Pass
```

Comment: Just out of interest where would I add an inner join to my Query?

Comment: In the inside where `@t` is. `@t` itself should be your table name. Instead of returning all columns, add 1 more, which is the `s1` manipulation. Subquery it, and perform the `s2` manipulation again.

Comment: Out of interest if I wanted to get just 68.6 can I take part of the string from 191 onwards?